# Edge cube is colored

Tags: puzzle

If I have a 3x3x3 cube and color it. Then I break it apart into 1x1x1 cubes. If I pick up a cube and see that it has color, what is the probability that it's edge cube.

My attempt:

Out of 27 1x1x1 cubes, 26 have color. Then there are 8 edge cubes on the top, 8 on the bottom and then 4 at the side. So the answer should be 20/26. Can someone confirm?

EDIT:

If consider edge cubes different from corner cubes, then it should be 12/26.

Comment: I thought edge cubes were different from corner cubes?

Comment: Or is a corner cube a type of edge cube?  It all depends on what the definition of "edge cube" is.

Comment: If consider edge cubes different from corner cubes, then it should be 12/26.

Comment: Your calculations look right to me.